# Skip the number of words, located in a String, indicated by one parameter

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I am getting stuck in this part of the exercise. What I have to do is to create a function call skipWords() that takes a string and a integer as arguments. This function should return a pointer to a substring of sentence.
for example, if this parameter has the value 0, a pointer that points to the beginning of the string should be returned (that is, no words are skipped). If the parameter has the value 1, a pointer to the second word should be returned (One word is skipped), etc. This function can't print anything and it can't take any input from me.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<strings.h> // We include this library to manipulate text strings.
#include<ctype.h>
#define SIZE 200
void printFirstWord(char sentence[], char *pointer[])
{
    int i,j=1;
    for(i=1;sentence[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        pointer[0]=&sentence[0];
        if(isalpha(sentence[i]))
        {
            if(!(isalpha(sentence[i-1])))
                pointer[j]=&sentence[i];
                j++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;pointer[i]!=NULL;i++)
    {
        printf("Word number %d: ", i);
        while(*pointer[i]!= ' ' && *pointer[i]!='\0')// This will print each character until it reaches a space or the end of the array.
        {
            printf("%c",*pointer[i]);
            *pointer[i]++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void skipWords(char sentence[],int words)
{
    int i;
    char *pointer[SIZE]={NULL};
    for(i=0;pointer[i]!=NULL;i++)
    {
        if()
    }


}

int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    char answer='y';
    char *pointer[SIZE]={NULL};
    char sentence[SIZE]={};
    while(answer=='y')
    {
        printf("Write a sentence: ");
        gets(sentence);
        printFirstWord(sentence, pointer);
        printf("Enter another sentence (y/n)? ");
        scanf("%c%*c",&answer);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

I don't know how to start this new function.

Comment: Why do you have printFirstWord function? It is not part of your task. Where do you call your skipWords function? Why skipWords is void, it should return a pointer, as you wrote. Read a sentence, read a number, then call your skipWords function, then print what it returned.

Comment: I'm not calling the function yet. This is an exercise that have differents assignment that, at the end will have just one function called printWord which is a mix of this two functions (printFirstWord and skipWords). Assignment 1 is create the function printFirstWord, this one is the second assignment(where I am stuck)

Comment: Do not show us code that is not relevant to the question. This is confusing. By the way, your function printFirstWord should have only one argument: the string (aka sentence). What you write there looks like "return first word".

Comment: I supposed skipWords is void, but I should change it to int. Yeah I was thinking about putting only one argument to printFirstWord, but I would have to declare the pointer "POINTER" all the time

Comment: Why to int? if it returns int, what will you do with it? (a spoiler: if it returns a pointer, you could feed it to printFirstWord...)

Comment: I don't know what I am doing right know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need the return type to be a char pointer, then you need the array's len unless it is a null terminated string and then you can call strlen() to get the string's length,
to count the words simply count spaces that are followed by a none space char(begining of word) 
BTW, i assume that by "word" you mean sequence of characters excluding spaces.. :

```
char* skipWords(char s[], int slen, int words)// OR (char* s, int words)
{
    int i = 0;

    if(slen > 0 && isalpha(s[0]))
        words--;

    for(i=0; i < slen - 1;i++)
    {
        if(words == 0)
        {
             return s + i;
        }

        if(isspace(s[i]) && isalpha(s[i+1]))
        {
             words--;
        }
    }

  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what this new code part do. Sorry but pointers are my weakness for now and I don't know how to connect the functions very well.

Comment: Those are different questions, and should be a bit more specific

Comment: Sorry. What I have to do in this part is that the "skipWords ()" function should return a pointer to a substring of sentence. The function should skip the number of words indicated by the parameter words.  Like this examples:

Comment: : char *ptr1;     ptr1 = skipWords("there you go",1); -> ptr1 points to "you go".             what I don't know how to do is connect the function "skipWords" and function "printFirstWord" to have an output like in the example

Comment: Also there is another task after this one where I have to use(call) this functions to create a new function printWord(). This new function must print one selected word from a given string. They give me a HINT: the string that is returned from skipWords() starts with the word that shuld be printed.

Comment: Finally a got it. It was usefull. Thank you @Dr.Haimovitz!!